# jQuery variable becomes undefined for no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, undefined

I have the following code, in which I want to save the content of the file `bar.txt` in the variable `foo`:

```
var foo;

jQuery.get('http://example.com/bar.txt', function(data) {
     foo = data;
     alert(foo);
});        

alert(foo);
```

The problem is that apparently, after the jQuery function ends the variable becomes undefined (even though it was declared **outside** that scope). The first `alert(foo)` displays the content of the file properly, but the second one displays nothing.

Can anybody tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is how asynchronous programming works**. The `$.get` function "ends" when the callback handler is called, not in a linear fashion by following the code.

The "first" `alert()` that will trigger when you run this code is the one you called on the last line (outside `$.get` the handler), by that time the ajax request has not yet been completed.

The second `alert` will happen when the ajax is completed (inside the `$.get` handler), and will display the data that you assigned to the variable, coming from the handler argument.

Some comments to your code, hopefully you’ll understand better:

```
var foo; // foo is now undefined

jQuery.get('http://example.com/bar.txt', function(data) {
     // the code in this handler will be executed after the ajax is complete
     foo = data;
     alert(foo); // foo is now the contents of bar.txt, this will happen last
});        

alert(foo); // foo is still undefined, and this alert happens first
```

You can program this differently if you need an example on how to "reuse" the foo variable:

```
var foo;

jQuery.get('http://example.com/bar.txt', function(data) {
     foo = data;
     onData();
});        

function onData() {
    alert(foo);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then how can I save the data that I obtain inside `$.get` handler in a variable that's on the outside?

Comment: You can’t "save" it for later, unless you do a synchronous call wich is not recommended. The callback is the place where you "continue" your running code. You might as well get your head around asynchronous programming now because you will use a lot of it later on :)

Comment: Yes, I think I understood, it's very awkward though as I'm used to "linear" programming. I put all the code (that manipulates the content of the text file) inside the $.get and it worked! so thanks man

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var foo;

jQuery.get('http://example.com/bar.txt', function(data) {
     window.foo = data;
     alert(foo);
});        

alert(foo);
```

Comment: No luck :/ still returns "undefined"